# Nunjucks rendering file paths relative to route being called and overriding express.static setting

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

Using Nunjucks with Node

Trying to figure out a graceful solution to the following problem. With a directory tree sorda like this:

`app_dir
--app.js
--public
----stylesheets
------mystyles.css
--views
----page.html
----templates
------page_template.html`

1. Have static files like CSS inside my public directory 
   `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
2. Have the root directory of Nunjucks configured as views
   `nunjucks.configure('views', {
   autoescape: true,
   express   : app,
   watch: true
   });`
3. When I am referencing a css file from within page_template.html, nunjucks (I think) automagically creates a relative path based on the route and overrides the static behavior.

For example, when I use `/stylesheets/mystyles.css` path on page_template.html but call the file that extends it using 
`/:publication/:page` path, the rendered html is  `/:publication/:page/stylesheets/mystyle.css`

I can always write a quick hack that creates relative paths to CSS and other resources based on the route but that doesn't feel like a particularly graceful solution :( Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I am referencing a css file from within page_template.html, nunjucks (I think) automagically creates a relative path based on the route and overrides the static behavior.

I think it's mistake. Nunjucks don't generate any path.
In template from any folder (`view`, `view/templates`, etc) you must specify filename considering that `public dir` is root, e.g.
`/stylesheets/mystyles.css` for `%app%/public/stylesheets/mystyles.css`.

I use subfolders in `view` for grouping templates, e.g. `/macros` (stored macros), `/tools` (stored additional pages for my app). Also you can use it to router, e.g. `/user/view.html`, `user/add.html`...